# How to Define 'onSlide' Callback Function of Primefaces Slider Component?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a primefaces slider component

```
<h:inputHidden id="animhidden"/>
<p:slider widgetVar="animslide" onSlide="slideAnimation()" for="animhidden" />
```

I define `slideAnimation` function, it is being called when I move the slider. But when I get the current value with `PF('animslide').getValue()` or `$('#animhidden').val()`, they get the previous value, not the new value of the slider.

So, How should I define `slideAnimation` function and get the new value of the slider wiht javascript?

Comment: try to read it in the `onSlideEnd` client side event handler of the `<p:slider>` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the primefaces documentation `onSlideEnd` function is defined as below. I tried the same for `onSlide` function it worked. Here is the way for the people who is searching for the same issue:

```
<p:slider widgetVar="animslide" onSlide="slideAnimation(event, ui)" for="animhidden" />

function slideAnimation(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.value);
}
```

You can also set value with -> `PF('animslide').setValue(value)`